# Referencing a column inside a data frame which inside another data frame

Tags: r

I imported the following dataframe (cm_countries) from a World Bank library:

```
structure(list(name = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria"), 
    region = c("SAS", "ECS", "MEA"), incomeLevel = c("LIC", "UMC", 
    "UMC"), capitalCity = c("Kabul", "Tirane", "Algiers"), geo = structure(list(
        lat = c(34.5228, 41.3317, 36.7397), lng = c(69.1761, 
        19.8172, 3.05097)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame"), 
    landlocked = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)), row.names = c(NA, 3L
), class = "data.frame")
```

| name | region | incomeLevel | capitalCity | geo.lat | geo.lng | landlocked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | SAS | LIC | Kabul | 34.52280 | 69.17610 | TRUE |
| Albania | ECS | UMC | Tirane | 41.33170 | 19.81720 | FALSE |
| Algeria | MEA | UMC | Algiers | 36.73970 | 3.05097 | FALSE |

Say I wanted to filter latitudes greater than 60, I wanted to use the code:

```
cm_countries %>%
  filter(geo.lat>60)
```

But I got an error that the column geo.lat wasn't found. When I checked the structure of the dataframe, I found:

```
'data.frame':   218 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ name       : chr  "Afghanistan" "Albania" "Algeria" "American Samoa" ...
 $ region     : chr  "SAS" "ECS" "MEA" "EAS" ...
 $ incomeLevel: chr  "LIC" "UMC" "UMC" "UMC" ...
 $ capitalCity: chr  "Kabul" "Tirane" "Algiers" "Pago Pago" ...
 $ geo        :'data.frame':    218 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ lat: num  34.5 41.3 36.7 -14.3 42.5 ...
  ..$ lng: num  69.18 19.82 3.05 -170.69 1.52 ...
 $ landlocked : logi  TRUE FALSE FALSE NA NA FALSE ...
```

So geo is a data frame within the bigger dataframe.

I figured that one way I can reference geo.lat would be to just use this:

```
cm_countries %>%
  filter(geo$lat>60)
```

But is there any other way to reference that column? Or is there any way to integrate the geo sub-dataframe into the cm_countries dataframe?

Comment: Use `dput(yourdata)` an share the output in your question!

Comment: @Duck...just added it! My bad!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `base R`:

```
#Code
new <- cm_countries[cm_countries$geo$lat>60,]
```

The other option is rebuild the dataframe and then filter:

```
#Code
cm_countries2 <- cbind(cm_countries[,-5],cm_countries$geo)
#Filter
new <- cm_countries2 %>% filter(lat>60)
```